# Append string before printing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting JSON data from AJAX call. So, the JSON data has format like -

```
data[0].scores.sadness
```

So, the last part 'sadness' is one of the emotions. I have total 8 emotions. So, I don't want to print like -

```
data[0].scores.sadness, data[0].scores.anger
```

So, I have created one array with all 8 emotions -

```
var emotions = ['anger', 'contempt', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happiness', 'neutral', 'sadness', 'surprise'];
```

I am using Jquery to dynamically create few elements, in 'each' loop of jQuery I'm appending array to JSON response like this -

```
var emotionPer = $('<div>')
    .text(data[0].scores + "." + emotions[i])
    .appendTo(li);
```

The problem I'm facing is that, it is printing [object] [object].{name of emotion}

for example -

```
[object] [object].anger or [object] [object].sadness
```

Is there any way to interpret it like -

```
data[0].scores.anger
```

So , that I can get value of above.

Comment: Please post the JSON data returned before you process it.

Comment: `[
  {
    "faceRectangle": {
      "left": 68,
      "top": 97,
      "width": 64,
      "height": 97
    },
    "scores": {
      "anger": 0.00300731952,
      "contempt": 5.14648448E-08,
      "disgust": 9.180124E-06,
      "fear": 0.0001912825,
      "happiness": 0.9875571,
      "neutral": 0.0009861537,
      "sadness": 1.889955E-05,
      "surprise": 0.008229999
    }
  }
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.text(data[0].scores[emotions[i]])
```

You can access the value of a key inside an object by two ways:

1. `obj.key`
2. `obj["key"]`

**Why your method didn't work:**

```
var obj = {"name":"void", "on":"stackoverflow"};
var key = "on";

obj.on // stackoverflow
obj["on"] // stackoverflow
obj.key // Will be undefined
obj[key] // will be stackoverflow.
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh glad, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Curious to know - why first way did not work out? :D

Comment: @KalpeshSingh cause it is just a string, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @void Made sense. So these are ways to access. :)